# launching app with root authorization at login items?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, authentication, authorization

I want to execute my app at login items(When OS X Starts up).

While doing this, I also want to get root authorization automatically without the dialog which ask user name and password.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as starting a Mac `.app` bundle as root on startup. However, you can install a daemon process that is executed at startup (authenticated) that launches your `.app` bundle.

For more on `Launch Agents/Daemons` have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/BPSystemStartup.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172-SW1).